# Python: Marking duplicates in list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have an unordered python list, what I want is to create 2nd list which will tell either the values in the first list are duplicate or unique.
For duplicates i have to mark them as duplicate1, duplicate2 and so on.
I will create a dictionary from these lists and later on these will be use in pandas dataframe.

I am stuck on logic of 2nd_list, could someone please help.

```py
first_List = ['a',  'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c']
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```py
second_List = ['dup1', 'unique', 'dup1', 'dup2', 'unique', 'dup2']
```

Comment: You made a little typo error in 2nd list. You show "a" as unique and "d" as dup2.

Comment: I will do it ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the list by `index`, and for list value at given `index`, check if it is duplicate or not (`isDuplicate`) boolean is created in the code below, if it is a duplicate entry,  then count how many times the current value appeared in the list for the given `index` and append the string to the `second_List`

```py
second_List = []
for i in range(len(first_List)):
    isDuplicate = first_List.count(first_List[i]) > 1
    if isDuplicate:
        count = first_List[:i+1].count(first_List[i])
        second_List.append(f'dup{count}')
    else:
        second_List.append('unique')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
['dup1', 'unique', 'dup1', 'dup2', 'unique', 'dup2']
```

Here is the equivalent **List-Comprehension** as well, if you are interested!

```py
>>> [f'dup{first_List[:i+1].count(first_List[i])}' 
... if first_List.count(first_List[i]) > 1 
... else 'unique'
... for i in range(len(first_List))]

['dup1', 'unique', 'dup1', 'dup2', 'unique', 'dup2']
```

Answer (score 0):

To be short

```
first_List = ['a',  'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c']

d = {i:'' for i in first_List if first_List.count(i) > 1}
second_List = ['unique' if i not in d.keys() else f'dup{list(d.keys()).index(i)+1}' for i in first_List]
```

It works fine.

This is the same as

```
d = {i:'' for i in first_List if first_List.count(i) > 1}
second_List = list()
for i in first_List:
    text = 'unique' if i not in d.keys() else f'dup{list(d.keys()).index(i)+1}'
    second_List.append(text)
```